# I am auto generating controls on my view and when i pass it to controller its getting null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on the survey app where i am populating surveys questions dynamically to users, i have populated survey on view properly, but when i hit the submit button my post controller having null model,
can any body help me with this ?

I am using
Asp.net core MVC with .net5.0 framework
SQL Server 2019 express

This is my Enum

```
    public enum QuestionTypeEnum
    {
        [Display(Name ="Text Box")]
        SingleLineTextBox=0,

        [Display(Name = "Text Area")]
        MultiLineTextBox=1,

        [Display(Name = "Yes/No")]
        YesOrNo=2,

        [Display(Name = "Select")]
        SingleSelect=3,

        [Display(Name = "Multi Select")]
        MultiSelect=4 
    }

    These is my ViewModel

    public class PopulateSurveyViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(length: 200)]
        public string Tital { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Created On")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Created By")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Expiry Date")]
        public DateTime ExpireOn { get; set; }

        public virtual List<PopulateQuestionViewModel> SurveyQuestionList { get; set; }
    }

    public class PopulateQuestionViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string QuestionType { get; set; }

        public string QuestionText { get; set; }

        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Options> QuestionOptionsList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Options
    {
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string option { get; set; }
    }
```

1. PopulateSurveyViewModel have the survey details and list of Survey Questions
2. PopulateQuestionViewModel have question id and text and also have options list in case if there is multiple option for users to select like

Question : What is your favorite sport
Options below
1 - Football
2 - Hockey
3 - Tennis
4 - Cricket

My SurveyController

```
 public class SurveyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

        public SurveyController(ApplicationDbContext context, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _context = context;
            this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Populate(string surveyurl)
        {
            var survey = _context.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyURL == surveyurl);

            var surveyviewmodel = SurveyPopulateDTO.Attach(survey);

            surveyviewmodel.SurveyQuestionList = GetSurveyQuestion(surveyviewmodel.ID);

            return View(surveyviewmodel);
        }


        public List<PopulateQuestionViewModel> GetSurveyQuestion(int id)
        {
            var surveyquestions = _context.SurveyQuestions.Where(s => s.SurveyID == id).ToList();

            var questinlists = new List<PopulateQuestionViewModel>();

            foreach (var item in surveyquestions)
            {
                var q = _context.Question.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == item.QuestionID);

                var listofoptions = new List<Options>();
                var list = _context.QuestionOptions.Where(s => s.QuestionID == q.Id).ToList();

                foreach(var options in list)
                {
                    var option = new Options
                    {
                        OptionId = options.Id,
                        option = options.Options
                    };

                    listofoptions.Add(option);
                }
                

                var qvm = new PopulateQuestionViewModel
                {
                    Id = q.Id,
                    QuestionText = q.QuestionText,
                    QuestionType = q.QuestionType,                   
                    QuestionOptionsList = listofoptions
                };

                questinlists.Add(qvm);
            }

            return questinlists;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Populate(PopulateSurveyViewModel model)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is my View

```
@model SurveyApp.Models.ViewModel.PopulateSurveyViewModel
@using SurveyApp.Data
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Populate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}

<form asp-action="Populate" asp-controller="Survey" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="ID" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="CreatedBy" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="CreatedOn" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Tital" class="control-label"></label>
        <label class="control-label">@Model.Tital</label>
        <input asp-for="Tital" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <label class="control-label">@Model.Description</label>
        <input asp-for="Description" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ExpireOn" class="control-label"></label>
        <label class="control-label">@Model.ExpireOn</label>
        <input asp-for="ExpireOn" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    @{
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.SurveyQuestionList.Count; i++)
        {
            string cbId = "Question_" + Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionType) == Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.SingleLineTextBox))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText</label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Answer" class="form-control" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionType) == Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.MultiLineTextBox))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i]" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText</label>
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Answer" rows="7" cols="30" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionType) == Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.MultiSelect))
            {

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText</label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                    <br />
                    @{
                        for (var optoins = 0; optoins < Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList.Count; optoins++)
                        {
                            string questionoptionId = "Qoptions_" + Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].OptionId;
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].OptionId" />
                            <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].option" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].option</label>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].OptionId" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                            <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].option" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                            <br />
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            }

        }
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my view look like

[Click to view my View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD3Al.png)

and when i hit submit button my SurveyQuestionList is having null or 0 element

[Check my controller code result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg24J.png)

in model i have all fields of survey but not having any result of dynamically generated questions it should have all generated questions with there answers in list

can anybody please help me where i am making mistake i am not able to understand this.

Comment: According to your code, I have created a sample, it seems that everything works well on my asp.net core 5 applications. So, try to clear the browser data (cache, cookie and so on), then debug your code and check whether the code works well or not. If still not working, have you ever used JQuery Ajax to submit the form when click the submit button? I will share the sample code, please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` I think you missed this, for that it did not bind data properly.

```
<form asp-action="Populate" asp-controller="Survey" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Hi @Breet Lee I have try with adding enctype="multipart/form-data" but it still returning same result, model is still null

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I have create a sample using the following code, it works well on my application, please check it:

```
public class Options
{
    public int OptionId { get; set; }
    public string option { get; set; }
    //Add IsSelected property to check whether the this option is selected or not, when the question type is MultiSelect or SingleSelect
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Code in the View page (Populate.cshtml)

Change `<input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" value="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].OptionId" />`

to `<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].IsSelected" class="custom-checkbox" />`

The final view page resource as below:

```
    @model netcore5.Models.PopulateSurveyViewModel
    <form asp-action="Populate" asp-controller="Survey" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input asp-for="ID" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
        <input asp-for="CreatedBy" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
        <input asp-for="CreatedOn" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Tital" class="control-label"></label>
            <label class="control-label">@Model.Tital</label>
            <input asp-for="Tital" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
            <label class="control-label">@Model.Description</label>
            <input asp-for="Description" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ExpireOn" class="control-label"></label>
            <label class="control-label">@Model.ExpireOn</label>
            <input asp-for="ExpireOn" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        @{
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.SurveyQuestionList.Count; i++)
            {
                string cbId = "Question_" + Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionType) == Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.SingleLineTextBox))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Answer" class="form-control" />
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                }
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionType) == Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.MultiLineTextBox))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i]" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText</label>
                        <textarea asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Answer" rows="7" cols="30" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                }
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionType) == Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.MultiSelect))
                {

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionText" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                        <br />
                        @{
                            for (var optoins = 0; optoins < Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList.Count; optoins++)
                            {
                                string questionoptionId = "Qoptions_" + Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].OptionId;
                                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].IsSelected" class="custom-checkbox" />
                                <label asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].option" class="control-label">@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].option</label>
                                <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].OptionId" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                                <input asp-for="@Model.SurveyQuestionList[i].QuestionOptionsList[optoins].option" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
                                <br />
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                }

            }
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Code in the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Populate(string surveyurl)
    {
        //var survey = _context.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyURL == surveyurl);

        //var surveyviewmodel = SurveyPopulateDTO.Attach(survey);

        //surveyviewmodel.SurveyQuestionList = GetSurveyQuestion(surveyviewmodel.ID);
        var surveyviewmodel = new PopulateSurveyViewModel()
        {
            CreatedBy = "test@tcom",
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
            Description = "This is test survey",
            ExpireOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
            ID = 6,
            SurveyQuestionList = new List<PopulateQuestionViewModel>()
            {
                new PopulateQuestionViewModel()
                {
                    QuestionText="What suport you like",
                     QuestionOptionsList = new List<Options>()
                     {
                          new Options(){ option= "Cricket", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Football", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Hockey", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Tenis", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "BasketBall", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Rugbby", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "UFC", OptionId=101}, 
                     },
                      QuestionType = Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.MultiSelect).ToString(),
                       Id=1, 
                       
                },
                new PopulateQuestionViewModel()
                {
                    QuestionText="What fruit you like",
                     QuestionOptionsList = new List<Options>()
                     {
                          new Options(){ option= "Cricket", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Football", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Hockey", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Tenis", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "BasketBall", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "Rugbby", OptionId=101},
                          new Options(){ option= "UFC", OptionId=101},
                     },
                      QuestionType = Convert.ToInt32(QuestionTypeEnum.MultiSelect).ToString(),
                       Id=1,

                }
            },
            Tital = "General Purpose Survey"
        };
        return View(surveyviewmodel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Populate(PopulateSurveyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @Zhi Lv your solution worked i was missing "public bool IsSelected { get; set; }" this one once i have added this it's working